# Xcode Tips for Eclipse users?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, eclipse

I've been slowly working my way through the examples in Beginning iPhone Development and there are a few things that I have not been able to figure out, but I'm sure you guys can help me with it.

- In Eclipse there is a Source->Generate Getters/Setters, can you do something similar to synthesize properties in Xcode
- I also cannot seem to find a Refactor menu
- I'm also struggling to find the equivalent to Source->Override/Implement Methods

**--Edit--**
I failed to describe my problem it seems. I do know that synthesizing properties will generate getters/setters for me, but I am looking for a way to generate the @property/@synthesize code, by selecting the variables.

Short list to start with, but I will probably have more as my confusion grows in might.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will ignore that question and instead answer a different question:

Here is some stuff I found useful when I first got started

- [Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.1729.us/xcode/Xcode%20Shortcuts.png)
- [Custom Macros](http://www.turkeysheartrhinos.com/?p=8)

And to directly address your question, check out [Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html)

Comment: Excellent, what I was looking for. I just found this as well which just deals with properties http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/instance-variable-to-synthesized.html

Answer (score 3):

I've created a list about a lot of funcrions and features in Xcode which also contains a lot of features that you are used to in Eclipse (i'm using eclipse on a daily basis) which also include thins like displaying class hierarchy, search for classes, code completion, using Xcode with svn etc..

Xcode tips:
http://www.sodeso.nl/?p=674

Using Xcode with svn:
sodeso.nl/?p=599

Answer (score 2):

There's no way built in Xcode to make proprieties in an automated manner.

However, user script can do this. Take a look at [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/instance-variable-to-synthesized.html) article by Matt Gallagher.

Answer (score 1):

> In Eclipse there is a Source->Generate Getters/Setters, can you do something similar to synthesize properties in Xcode

AFAIK there isn't such a thing in Xcode. But synthesizing ObjC properties is simple, just add

```
@property(retain) NSArray* my_array;
```

in your `@interface` and

```
@synthesize my_array;
```

in your `@implementation`, if you want to generate getters and setters for `my_array`.

> I also cannot seem to find a Refactor menu

Edit -> Refactor (Shift-Cmd-J).

If you simply want to rename, mouse-click an identifier, wait for 1 seconds for a downward triangle to appear next to it, then click on it and choose "Edit All in Scope".

Comment: The `@synthesize` line is no longer needed as of later versions of Xcode 4. Xcode inserts that code implicitly for you. Xcode also implicitly declares an instance variable with the same name as property but prefixed with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Generating getters and setters for properties is done with the `@property` and the `@synthesize` keywords.

Edit -> Refactor

Overriding methods is just writing the method name, you don't have to add `@Override` like in Java.

Comment: @neohaven - Thanks for your answer, but what I am looking for is a way of automating the generation of @property and @synthesize tags. I am not talking about adding a @override tag to methods but copying the method template into the source file :)